# Taking latest non null record from multiple columns and bringing down to one row in SQL without iterating/looping

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a dataset which contains email, city, state, zip and date. What i need is one row for each emails and city, state and zip be filled with the latest non-null value available for each.

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

I am using a query like below but it is taking hours to run. Is there any other effecient way to get the desired output in SQL?

````
row_number()over(partition by Email_Addr order by email_effective_from desc) as rn1
into #d1 from data where zip is not null and email_addr is not null;
select Email_Addr,city,
row_number()over(partition by Email_Addr order by email_effective_from desc) as rn2 into #d2
from data where city is not null and email_addr is not null;
select Email_Addr,[state],
row_number()over(partition by Email_Addr order by email_effective_from desc) as rn3 into #d3
from data  where state is not null and email_addr is not null;
select a.email_addr,a.zip,b.city,c.[state] into #dff from #d1 a
full outer join #d2 b on a.email_addr=b.email_addr
full outer join #d3 c on a.email_addr=c.email_addr```
````

Comment: It is generally preferred that you include your test data as text within your question, so that those providing an answer can easily copy and paste it for testing purposes.

Comment: It might help if if you added some test data but also that the SQL is syntactically correct.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 4):

If you are running SQL Server 2022, one option uses `last_value` and `ignore nulls`:

```
select *
from (
    select email, date,
        last_value(city)  ignore nulls over(partition by email order by date) city,
        last_value(state) ignore nulls over(partition by email order by date) state,
        last_value(zip)   ignore nulls over(partition by email order by date) zip,
        row_number()                   over(partition by email order by date desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

| email | date | city | state | zip | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 2023-01-04 | B | JP | 160007 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SYJ80Tfc)

Or we can use `with ties` instead of filtering:

```
select top (1) with ties email, date,
    last_value(city)  ignore nulls over(partition by email order by date) city,
    last_value(state) ignore nulls over(partition by email order by date) state,
    last_value(zip)   ignore nulls over(partition by email order by date) zip,
    row_number() over(partition by email order by date desc) rn
from mytable t
order by row_number() over(partition by email order by date desc)
```

---

In earlier versions, one alternative uses a gaps-and-islands technique to build groups of rows, then aggregates over those groups:

```
select top (1) with ties email, date, 
    max(city)  over(partition by email, grp_city ) city,
    max(state) over(partition by email, grp_state) state,
    max(zip)   over(partition by email, grp_zip  ) zip
from (
    select t.*,
        count(city)  over(partition by email order by date) grp_city,
        count(state) over(partition by email order by date) grp_state,
        count(zip)   over(partition by email order by date) grp_zip
    from mytable t 
) t
order by row_number() over(partition by email order by date desc)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hCEo-Q-O)**

Comment: this solution looks very nice! but how about a solution which includes `group by`?

Comment: @YairMaron Use the `PARTITION BY` part to add your grouping columns

Comment: watch out with last_value, it usually doesn't work like one think it does :D

Comment: last_value dos not do anything here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```sql
declare @t table  (email varchar(100), city nvarchar(100),state nvarchar(100), zip nvarchar(10), date datetime)

insert into @t
values  ('a@b.com', 'A', '', '', '20210101')
,   ('a@b.com', '', 'MN', '160007', '20210102')
,   ('a@b.com', 'B', '', '', '20210103')
,   ('a@b.com', '', 'JP', '', '20210104')
,   ('a@a.com', 'Z', 'A', 'B', '20210103')
,   ('a@a.com', 'A', 'Z', '', '20210104')


select  STUFF(max(convert(varchar(8), date, 112) + nullif(city, '')), 1, 8, '') as city
,   STUFF(max(convert(varchar(8), date, 112) + nullif(state, '')), 1, 8, '') as state
,   STUFF(max(convert(varchar(8), date, 112) + nullif(zip, '')), 1, 8, '') as zip
,   email
,   max(date) as date
from    @t
group by email
```

We construct strings by appending them to date, and at the same time convert '' to NULL, this simplifies our aggregation.

Then after performing MAX aggregation, we deconstruct the strings by removing the date part, this leaves the real last value per date.